# Can SVN (eclipse plugin) automatically sync commits to my project folder?

Tags: svn, dvcs

I'm pretty new to SVN, and on a project I've joined everyone does `Update to HEAD` manually to sync recent commits to their local project.

As I don't know better I'm thinking this is a lot of wasted effort.

- Is there a way to automatically sync commits in SVN?
- Is there a reason why I should not ask such a question?
- Is this easier/better/safer in DVCS's such as Git/Mercurial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no automatic sync feature in SVN. The reason may be your your code changes can broke entire project work flow (which may affect your local testing) and you can take care of it after your module is completely coded. After your code changes are completed, you update your code and check that everything is fine and if not, you can fix any broken code flow.

The best practice is:

- create a branch for your live.
- do changes in your branch.
- merge your changes with updated main trunk (updated to head revision).